# Spring starter security-basic auth-vai zuul server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, netflix-zuul

I have zuul server vai which I am calling OAuth's server to get token vai postman,if I request by sending cilent credentials in body I get token back but when I choose to get it via send client credentials in basic-auth header I am getting unauthorised 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved after adding

```
    @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity.ignoring()
               .antMatchers("/auth/**");
}
```